# Sending csv file via FTP to PythonAnywhere

Tags: ftp, pythonanywhere

My organisation uses Business Objects as a layer over its Oracle database so that people like me (i.e. not in the IT dept) can access the data without the risk of breaking something.

I have a PythonAnywhere account where I have a few dashboards built using Flask.

Each morning, BO sends me an email with the cvs files of the data that I want. I then upload these to a MYSQL server, and go from there. There is also an option to send it to an FTP recipient...but that's pretty much it.

Is it possible to set up an FTP server on my (paid for) PythonAnywhere account? If I could have those files go to a dir like `/data`, I could then have a scheduled job to insert them into my DB.

The data is already in the public domain and not sensitive.

Or is there intact a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here: we don't support regular FTP, unfortunately.  If there was a way to tell BO to send the data via an HTTP POST to a website, then you could set up a simple Flask app to handle that -- but I'm guessing from what you say that it doesn't :-(

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this, but here are some additional options on PythonAnywhere: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/FTP